# ReactJs : Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error for a very basic example of ReactJs.

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<h1>Hi</h1>);
    }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: can you please show your HTML file you are trying to render to?

Comment: can you also make your code legible? In more than one line?

Comment: @Chaim: my html code just display Hi message. <h1>Hi</h1>

Comment: I am not referring to your JSX. `document.getElementById('app')` this line is looking for an element with the ID of app to render your component to. My guess is that your issue is somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element with an ID of `app` in your HTML file. Typically, you'd just have an empty div in the body.

```
<body>
  <div id="app></div>
</body>
```

For more info see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted seems fine. Most likely the problem is in with HTML part.

For a starting point, you can take a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/74rq1z90vj